# Java BouncyCastle signing without a passphrase

Tags: java, bouncycastle, openpgp

I am using bcpg-jdk16 version 1.46 with Java 8 and have attempted to,based on the examples (https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples), sign a file with a PGP key generated on another system.

The PGP keys in question has no associated passphrase.

When we attempt to sign using the example code the file I receive an exception "checksum mismatch at 0 of 20"

Which seems to indicate that the passphrase is incorrect. Based on a quick inspection of the library.

I attempt the same with a certificate that was generated with a passphrase and this was able to generate signatures for the file in question.

I am not overly familiar with these security aspects so the question is whether this is an issue with the bouncy castle library itself.

using gpg I am able to sign and verify the file with both certificates without issue.

Comment: Did you try passing an _empty_ passphrase (ie., the empty string?). Is the exported key valid, can you import it in GnuPG?

Comment: Yes I attempted and empty string example: ""  @Jens Erat also thanks for taking the time to look at this

Comment: the offending method seems to be extractKeyData within the PGPSecretKey class but I have no idea whether this is expected behaviour or there is some configuration I should be applying

Comment: I was able to import the certificates via the cli this is being tested on ubuntu systems

Comment: If you import the key in GnuPG, set a passphrase and export it again, does it work in BouncyCastle? Just to be sure it's not just some incompatibility with BouncyCastle. I'm not really familiar with BouncyCastle, but that's what I'd try first.

Comment: I could be very wrong here but it seems there was a problem with the import specifically there was an "error building the skey array" which results in me failing to update the password when i run the command gpg --edit-key _key_; passwd . The error when I attempt to change the password is *Need the secret key to do this*. Though the command gpg --list-keys list the key along with my other keys and appears to be successful when signing a file when I imported the key a gui prompt to enter the passphrase did occur

Comment: Run `gpg --list-packets [keyfile]` on the key you're trying to import. This should help at understanding whether the file actually includes a private key.

Comment: I compared the output of this from 2 certificates one which worked with the bouncy castle library and had a pass phrase and one which did not work and did not have a passphrase and I could not determine any difference.I will mail the bouncy-castle mailing list to see if I can get some advise around this